# How can I speed up this process since it takes a very long time to copy and paste?

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

Is there anyway to combine to following steps since I am pulling the data from the same sheet into another sheet and the process is very slow.

```
Sheets("CDGL").Select
Sheets("CDGL").Range("H2:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Rec").Range("B6")

Sheets("CDGL").Select
Sheets("CDGL").Range("L2:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Rec").Range("E6")

Sheets("CDGL").Select
Sheets("CDGL").Range("AJ2:AJ" & Cells(Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp).Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Rec").Range("I6")
```

Comment: Do you need the formatting, borders, conditional formats and data validation rules to follow, or just the values? If only the values, union the ranges to be copied, dump the source data into an array, then dump the array into the destination. Should be pretty much instant.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I just need the values to be copied and pasted...can you please post the coding for it so I can see the visual

Comment: FYI, there is no need to select the sheet when using the Range.Copy Destination:= format.  (Further, there is DEFINITELY no need to select a sheet that is already selected)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply assign the values directly using the Resize() Function to make the ranges the same size:

```
With Sheets("CDGL")
    Sheets("Rec").Range("B6").Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row - 1, 3).Value = .Range("H2:J" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    Sheets("Rec").Range("E6").Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row - 1, 4).Value = .Range("L2:O" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    Sheets("Rec").Range("I6").Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp).Row - 1, 1).Value = .Range("AJ2:AJ" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With
```

I also used a With Block and the Appropriate `.` identifier to reduce typing and removing the continual selection of sheets.  This will also cut down the time.

Comment: Hi @scott Craner, thank you but the process still takes a long time...any other recommendation?

Comment: Then there are other things in your sub that causes this.  Make sure you go through your code and find ways to remove any `.Select` and `.Activate`.

Answer (score 0):

When you need a fast copy/paste, avoid copying to clipboard and pasting again. You could have simply used the Range.Value method, something like the following:

```
With Sheets("CDGL")
rows_c1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Rec").Range("B6:D" & rows_c1).Value = Sheets("CDGL").Range("H2:J" & rows_c1).Value

rows_c2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Rec").Range("E6:H" & rows_c2).Value = Sheets("CDGL").Range("L2:O" & rows_c2).Value

rows_c3 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Rec").Range("I6:I" & rows_c3).Value = Sheets("CDGL").Range("AJ2:AJ" & rows_c3).Value
End With
```

Should you need to have the formatting of cells copied, the Range property "Value" can have 3 optional arguments 10,11,12. 11 is what you need to transfer both value, formats, and formulas.
Something like this:

```
Sheets("Rec").Range("B6:D" & rows_c1).Value(11) = Sheets("CDGL").Range("H2:J" & rows_c1).Value(11)
```

Also, avoid using "Select" and use the "With....End With" statement to speed up the execution.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue isn't the effectiveness of the code but the time it takes to work, add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to the start of your sub and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` to the end.  This will speed up the wait time immensely